# Can quantum field theory be done with a Hamiltonian instead of a Lagrangian?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

Quantum field theory is based on the Lagrangian and the path integral method explores, via the partition, all kinds of paths, like all paths in classical mechanìcs are explored, from which one is chosen, namely the one with the least action (which involves the Lagrangian). In QFT all paths actually contribute with varying weights.

Classical mechanics though can be done in a Hamiltonian way too. The Lagrangian represents $T-V$, while the Hamiltonian represents their sum, $T+V$. So both the potential energy as kinetic energy are involved. And indeed, in classical mechanics the Hamiltonian is used to determined position and momentum.

Can the Hamiltonian approach be used in QFT? Without trying all paths? Would this amount to cakculating all possible positions and associated particle momenta at all times, and the associated weights?  If so, is there a reason why the Lagrangian is used and not the Hamiltonian? Why is the situation in classical quantum mechanics the opposite?

Comment: Of course it can. Have a look at [canonical quantisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_quantization#Second_quantization:_field_theory)

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə Ah! So it's just second quantisation? The ordinary  SE quantised? Or the Dirac equation quantised? Is it just that?

Comment: Yes, to the first question. To the second question, I don't know what you mean by SE.

Comment: It should be noted that the path integral can be justified from the hamiltonian. There's also "Hamiltonian action" though quite marginal, that can be used in the path integral approach.

Comment: Take a look at [this document](https://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys851/Luty/notes/pathint.pdf) in the first few pages.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/238316/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78508/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21866/2451

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə Sorry. I meant the Schrödinger equation (SE).

Comment: I mean, it's always the Lagrangian (density) asked for, and the equation of motion can be derived from the EL equations. Though you can arrive at the Schrödinger equation by a Hamiltonian because that's used. Substituting the operators for p, x, and E in E=T+V directly gives you the SE. Or in the relativistic case ($E^2 = m^2 + p^2$). The Lagrangian is normally the starting point.

Comment: see https://people.phys.ethz.ch/~nbeisert/lectures/QFT1-19HS-Notes.pdf